# .NET 6 WPF Can't change opacity in code behhind?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, code-behind

I've been trying to change the opacity of my window through code for a while now but I've had no success. I'm changing the `Window.Opacity` number in my function but I've had no results. As of now, I've tried setting the background to a `SolidBrushColor` and setting the opacity from there but nothing happens. I'm also trying `INotifyPropertyChanged` still to no avail. There are no errors either. The opacity just isn't affected. Here is the code of the overlay window that needs its opacity changed:

```cs
public partial class overlay : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public static overlay? thisOverlay;
        DoubleAnimation fade = new DoubleAnimation(0, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)));

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

        private double _windowOpacity;
        public double WindowOpacity
        {
            get => _windowOpacity;
            set
            {
                if (_windowOpacity == value)
                    return;

                _windowOpacity = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public overlay()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += Overlay_Loaded;
            WindowOpacity = 0.2;
        }

        private void Overlay_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            thisOverlay = this;

        }
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }

        public void setOpacity() // Function is ran outside of this class
        {
            this.WindowOpacity = 0.5; // This doesn't work
            Trace.WriteLine("Works"); // This prints
        }
```

and here is the XAML code for the window:

```xml
<Window x:Class="NAME.overlay"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NAME"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="overlay" Height="450" Width="800" WindowState="Maximized" WindowStyle="None" Topmost="True" AllowsTransparency="True" Opacity="{Binding WindowOpacity}" Visibility="Hidden">
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the binding to your custom property to work you should set the `DataContext`:

```
public overlay()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Loaded += Overlay_Loaded;
    WindowOpacity = 0.2;
    DataContext = this;
}
```